# Why aren't I considered illegitimate?

Tags: catholicism, marriage

So, my dad is a baptized Catholic, but was raised Presbyterian. When he was in his twenties he married a woman in the Catholic Church who left him within a year (and got married to his best man... sad but true). There has never been effort to annul this union (it is moot now, she is dead).

Several years later he met an married my mom (another relationship which did not last). According to the Catholic Church this can't be a valid marriage because my dad's first wife was still alive. I was told that I was considered legitimate by the Church but shouldn't I be considered illegitimate?

Comment: And, to further complicate things, since my dad and mom are divorced and my dad's first wife died, his marriage to his current wife is *probably* valid.

Comment: was your dad a practicing Catholic when married to his first wife? (I'm not sure this matters, but it would make things clear) I did a bit of looking in to the matter for [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7328/has-the-notion-of-legitimacy-been-abandoned-in-the-catholic-church)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is important about "being legitimate"? I assume it's more than just being an heir to his estate.

Comment: @mojo Mostly a point of curiosity. There was a time in the U.S. where illegitimacy actually prevented some from Holy Orders. It won't come up anymore (and I can't really do much beyond deacon anyway w/o my wife getting annoyed), but it was important once.

Comment: @mojo As noted in the question Peter Turner linked to, CIC #1137 does mention it.

Comment: @PeterTurner Practicing doesn't matter as much as form and intent do. He was a validly baptized Catholic (making him eligible for matrimony), the marriage was with another Catholic, and the marriage happened in a Catholic Church. And they were married by a priest. Now, while I believe it could have been annulled had they tried, the official position of the Church, I believe, is that a marriage is valid (and binding) until proven otherwise.

Comment: @PeterTurner It would be very difficult to argue that my dad was not married to his first wife.

Comment: OK, so how about the second marriage, were your mom and dad married in a Catholic Church? (don't want to scandalize anyone, but this has been known to happen) If so, I think you've got the answer right there. You can't be illegitimate if your parents were not conscience that the form of their marriage was invalid.  I'll look it up again for you if you want, but that's the gist of what I read on the other question. I think that makes for a putative marriage, but then again, I think this question is garnering the close votes because it seems to others like pastoral advice, so maybe it is!

Comment: They did not marry in the Church. But that does cause another question: why wouldn't I be illegitimate if I were the child of an annulled marriage?

Comment: To answer the last comment explicitly, children cannot become illegitimate. If a valid marriage is annulled, it doesn't change the status of any children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, apparently (or at least according to a [deacon who is citing a canon lawyer](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/deaconsbench/2012/07/on-alec-baldwins-wedding-and-his-daughters-illegitimate-status/)), Canon law would say that my parent's marriage was putative and, as such, I can be considered a legitimate son.

Answer (score 0):

Define legitimate.

If your definition is - Children born by the union of a man and wife married by God’s law.

Then what about the following verse –

> And do not think you can say to yourselves, 'We have Abraham as our father.' 
>   I tell you that out of these stones God can raise up children for Abraham. (Mat 3:9)

Would such children be legitimate?

God uses the term legitimate in different contexts -

1. The term is applied to those who aren’t obedient to God.

   “If God doesn't discipline you as he does all of his children, it means that you are illegitimate and are not really his children at all.” (NLT Heb 12:8)
2. God calls the Israelites illegitimate because their mother Israel
   prostituted herself to foreign gods. (Can't remember the reference though)

God’s perspective on legitimacy is not limited to physical circumstances of one’s birth.

But supposing that one is born illegitimately, so what? Remember John 3:5? (One must be reborn of the spirit).

> “Shouldn't I be considered illegitimate?”

By whom? God? Nope. I don’t think so. 
There are illegitimate parents, but there aren’t any illegitimate children.

Comment: From the question and its tags, I think the answer to "Define *legitimate*" would be "Legitimate according to Roman Canon Law", which this answer doesn't address.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Hmmm I thought of that too. Now wondering if I should delete it..